# Kali installer cannot detect any drive other than usb

Tags: kali-linux, system-installation, hard-disk

I am trying to dual boot kali linux on Acer extensa 15 machine with windows 10 (I have changed SATA To AHCI) and I made 40 gb unallocated space (BASIC) but none of my drive are being detected by kali installer other than than USB drive .

PS:I am performing graphical install.

Answer (score 0):

This is very little information.

While in the kali installer try to get on a terminal, run `lsblk` to list all block devices (i.e. storage devices), to see if the operating system detects it.

If yes, try creating a partition at the unallocated space with `parted` and see if the installer will detect it then.

If no, then it is more likely to be something with the firmware or BIOS, try all the BIOS settings for SATA as you already started.

Try another Linux installer to check if they detect the drive to find out if it is specific to that kali installer.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same, went into BIOS disabled all security. Worked fine after.